# Why am I getting the number of rows in an Excel sheet as 0 using JAVA?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to write some data into an Excel file with format (.xlsx). But the thing is that the first row of it is written into the file correctly and when I am trying to retrieve the number of rows and then increment the rows so that I could write more rows into the file, I am getting an exception of "Invalid format exception" and sometimes my code is getting executed but I am getting row count as 1. Please solve my issue and I am even attaching the code am working with.

```
public static int getRows(String memail,String testid) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException, InvalidFormatException{
            int rc;         

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("email1.xlsx"));

                XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook (file);
                WorkbookFactory.create(file);

                XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(testid);

                rc = sheet.getLastRowNum();

               return rc;

       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following line

```
   WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

and try again.

If you have already a created file, while you are creating that again...

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getPhysicalNumberOfRows%28%29), this will returns the number of physically defined rows (NOT the number of rows in the sheet).
One more point are you sure you are getting the correct sheet from `wb.getSheet(testid);`?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the correct sheet and the thing is that only one record is getting saved into the sheet and the remaining are not. The thing is that it is working fine with other excel workbooks. I could like to know whether there will be any problem with writing into files. I even tried with getPhysicalNumberofRows() but I did not get the result.